# How to point to the previous node of the current node and the next node of the current node in C?

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes

Till now, in Linked List, I have only used a single `temp` node to traverse a given linked list for different operaitons which is very easy.

Now an assignment of a book demands to write a C code where the user input would be a number in the list and we have to compare the number just before the given number and the number just after the given number and tell which one is greater or equal, in case. For that, according to me, we need two pointers viz. `prev` and `next` on both side of `current` node to point to the two numbers at the different nodes and then collecting there data part we can compare them. But I can not code this part in C. So a code snippet to point to the required nodes would be helpful.

Comment: Just look at your own `add_at_end` code snippet and work towards the solution from there.

Comment: @PaulEvans, How? I am not using two more different nodes here.

Comment: You need to modify your node struct to have a `next` AND `prev` pointer. Then you can assign to both in your `add_at_end` function.

Comment: @jonhopkins, I do not need to incorporate them in the current code. My assignment is different. Perhaps, the code was misleading you. I have deleted the irrelevant code now.

Comment: Okay. Well changing the struct is one option, and the easier one in my opinion. But if you need to maintain a pointer to the node previous to the current node in your search, a simple way is to check if `node->NEXT` is the node you're looking for. Then `node` is your `prev`, `node->NEXT` is your `current`, and `node->NEXT->NEXT` is your `next`.

Comment: Freddie's answer is another option, and it is more readable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a prev pointer. You just need a temporary variable to keep track of the previous and current node like so:

```
prevNode = NULL;
curNode = *p;

while (curNode != NULL)  
{
  prevNode = curNode;
  curNode = curNode->next;
}
```

Once you find where you want to do your comparisons, you can use prevNode's data, curNode's data and curNode->next's data. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of doing this.

1. Use a doubly linked list

   ```
   typedef struct node {
       struct node *prev, next;
       int data;
   } node_t;

   /*
    * Return 1 if prev data is greater then next data, else 0.
    * return -1 if invalid input.
    */
   int compare(node_t *head, int num)
   {
       node_t *p;

       if (head == NULL || head->data == num || head->next == NULL)
          return -1;

       p = head->next;

       while (p->next != NULL) {
           if (p->data == num) {      
               return (p->prev->data > p->next->data ? 1 : 0);
           }
           p = p->next;
       }

       return -1;
   }
   ```
2. Singly linked list

   ```
   typedef struct node {
       struct node *next;
       int data;
   } node_t;

   /*
    * Return 1 if prev data is greater then next data, else 0.
    * return -1 if invalid input.
    */
   int compare(node_t *head, int num)
   {
       node_t *p, *q;

       if (head == NULL || head->data == num || head->next == NULL)
          return -1;

       p = head;
       q = head->next;

       while (q->next != NULL) {
           if (q->data == num) {      
               return (p->data > q->next->data ? 1 : 0);
           }
           p = q;
           q = q->next;
       }

       return -1;
   }
   ```